# After downloading the blockchain from scratch overnight, the daemon stalls with 118,508 blocks. What can I do to resolve this?

Tags: monerod, synchronization

My original monerod.exe would not open for more than a second before closing. I could see no reason, so after many attempts, I backed up the blockchain that I had, (behind by a week) and started downloading the chain from scratch, letting it run overnight.

As it closed in on the last 120,000 blocks, it slowed considerably, and has now stopped.

I believe that I set the log level at two before that last forced update, but I cannot find any log file that seems useful.

Answer (score 3):

Ring CT started up somewhere around that block.  If you do not have the latest Monero version, you will never synch up with the network.  You have to keep up with the latest software versions.  Also, the last remaining blocks are much slower than the others because of Ring CT.

An SSD speeds things up 4 to 5 times faster in comparison to an HDD.  If you don't have one, get one.  They're cheap.